# Prolog construction of a list using =../2

Tags: list, prolog

I want to construct from a list like this: `[name1(value1), name2(value2),...]` a list like this: `[value1, value2,...]`, and I have the following code:

```
    construct_listv([],_).
    construct_listv([A0|T], Values) :-
        A0 =.. [_, Value],
        append([Value], [], Values),
        construct_listv(T, Values).
```

if I put for example `construct_listv([su(2), se(5)], ResultList)`.

can anyone tell me why the second call to append fails and the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Values` where two results are needed, and thus at cross-purposes.

Note that the recursive case of **construct_listv/2** needs to deal with both Head and Tail of the first argument.  Each will contribute to the construction of the second argument, but you have the **append/3** determining that output, in conflict with how the recursive call to **construct_listv/2** wants to determine it.

Perhaps what you meant was:

```
construct_listv([],[]).
construct_listv([A0|T], [V|Values]) :-
    A0 =.. [_, V],
    construct_listv(T, Values).
```

Now you no longer need any call to **append/3**.  The recursion takes care of building the output argument for you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
construct_list(L1, L2) :-
    maplist(construct_one, L1, L2).

construct_one(X, V) :-
    X =.. [_, V].
```